# Linux image viewer to create and manage collections (lists of images)

Tags: linux, images, image-editor, image-viewer

I am looking for a simple image viewer available for Linux Mint with the following features:

- Browsing folders with images
- Selecting and adding images to collections
- Removing images from collections
- Saving those collections as simple line based text files with on image file path per line

I have looked into [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) which comes close to what I need. It can load file lists, shows the contained images and allows me to remove images from that list. However, I could not find a way to *add* images to those file lists. Maybe there is some kind of extension?

Ideally, I would like to start the image viewer like this:

```
image-viewer --file-list=my_image_collection.txt --recursively ~/my_image_folder
```

By which I mean this: Show all images contained in `~/my_image_folder` and sub folders, mark all files listed in `my_image_collections.txt` and let me interactively add/remove files.

Comment: well... i don't know if there is such a application, but i can tell you the default image-organizer **`pix` with its *Catalogs*** is really close to your needs: the only thing, there is no GUI to save/export the catalog(s), but they are stored (with it's slideshow-settings) as xml-file under `~/.local/share/pix/catalogs/your-collection-name.catalog`. -- you can open & edit this xml-file with every text-editor.

Comment: With feh, you could add an action  `--action1 "echo %f >>list.txt"`, then when you type `1` the current filename is appended to the list via the shell. You had probably better not have feh handle this list at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

So to go the tui route there is [`fim`](https://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/), and you cam select images with `[enter]` allows you to print them to STD output (and thus a file). [`Feh`](https://feh.finalrewind.org/), which was mentioned in the comments, appeats to be int eh same vein (but I haven't personally used it).

After digging for a solution that solves a similar requirement [Geeqie](https://github.com/BestImageViewer/geeqie) solved it. You can have toggalable, visible marks. You can then copy them as a list of filenames.
To get the "one filename per line" just took a quick replace on the text editor.
A bit manual, but good enough for me.